# Accidentally Deleted Local Key Pair

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running an AWS EC2 VM for a school project. I accidentally deleted the local key pair on my computer then emptied my recycle bin on my Mac. I dont see a way to redownload the keypair.

There are important things running on the VM that I need.

Is it possible to redownload the local keypair?

I cant even seem to regenerate a new keypair to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to recover the access.

- AWS Systems Manager (SSM) automation
  To recover access to your Linux instance using AWS Systems Manager (SSM) automation, run the `AWSSupport-ResetAccess Automation` automation document. For more information, see [Reset Passwords and SSH Keys on Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-ec2reset.html).
- Manually recover access

To manually recover access to your Linux instance, create a new key pair to replace the lost key pair. For more information, see [Connecting to Your Linux Instance If You Lose Your Private Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair).

Comment: i am using a windows instance is it the same?

Comment: On these links, separate detail is mentioned for windows.